# Why doesn't the Perl regex match this string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this line in a CSV file:

```
[2/16/2012] emailed...I honestly do not know - I am an endpoint in sales – I would try contacting our corporate office. <STOP>
```

And this Perl regex:

```
m/\[(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\]\s(.*)/
```

I would expect this regex to match the above string. When I take out the "-" characters in the string, the regex matches. Otherwise, it doesn't. Why? I thought the "." character means any character except the newline? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does, and that works for me.

Comment: Nevermind, there is a problem with reading in the CSV file. The line wasn't even read in. It seems like the Text::CSV parser is throwing out the above line. Why?

Comment: @Andrew If that's a new question, perhaps you should add some details about your new situation.

Comment: It appears that I have UTF-8 encoded characters in the CSV file I'm reading. I think that's why it's failing to parse that one line. How can I read in this line? Do I need to somehow tell the parser to accept UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Could you please quote the `open` line from your script as well?

Comment: If you examine your dashes, you see that one of them is a bit longer than a normal dash.  It is an "en-dash", and it is not a standard ASCII character, so it has to be encoded in something like unicode or latin-1.  If you use the wrong encoding in your `open` statement, it will barf on this line.

Comment: If the question was never really a problem, you can delete it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks fine.  I tested with following one-liner it successfully captured both pieces from string.

```
$ perl -e 'my $str = "[2/16/2012] emailed...I honestly do not know - I am an endpoint in sales – I would try contacting our corporate office. <STOP>"; print "full str: $str\n"; if ($str =~ m/\[(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\]\s(.*)/) { print "matched\ndate: $1\nmsg: $2\n"; } else { print "did not match\n"; }'

full str: [2/16/2012] emailed...I honestly do not know - I am an endpoint in sales – I would try contacting our corporate office. <STOP>
matched
date: 2/16/2012
msg: emailed...I honestly do not know - I am an endpoint in sales – I would try contacting
our corporate office. <STOP>
```

The above one-liner in easier to read format:

```
my $str = "[2/16/2012] emailed...I honestly do not know - I am an endpoint in sales – I would try contacting our corporate office. <STOP>"; 
print "full str: $str\n"; 
if ($str =~ m/\[(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\]\s(.*)/) {
    print "matched\ndate: $1\nmsg: $2\n";
} 
else { 
    print "did not match\n"; 
}
```

Check to make sure there are no hidden metacharacters in your string.  If on linux, you can run dos2unix to remove any Windows added carriage returns.  If on windows, you can use notepad++ to show all characters.  View->Show all characters